# Difference between "inform of" and "inform that"

Tags: prepositions

Is it incorrect to say that **"I will inform students that tomorrow class will be cancelled?"**

Does the sentence mean same as this sentence **"I will inform students of that tomorrow class will be cancelled?"**

Comment: In both examples, "tomorrow class" should be changed to either "tomorrow's class" or "class tomorrow", or "tomorrow class will be cancelled" should be changed to "class will be cancelled tomorrow".

Answer (score 1):

If you have a verb like "to inform someone of <something>" and change the construction using a that-clause, the preposition (of etc) is dropped. The prepositions remain before clauses with "what".

- I informed her that I was unwell and could not come to her party.
- He informed us of what had happened.

Answer (score 0):

One informs **of** a fact, whereas one informs **that** a thing is so. In terms of the syntax, “to inform of” takes as its complement a noun phrase, whereas “to inform that” takes a clause.

> I was informed of her departure.

> I was informed that she had left.

The same goes for such other verbs as *learn* and *tell*.